# Can we sanitize data from XML before transforming it into HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xalan

We have written XSLT's to transform XML files into HTML. We would like to have this HTML to be free from any vulnerabilities. There should not be any suspicious scripts running into it.
So, can we implement something in XSLT which will validate XML content and flag it as inappropriate to be written into HTML?

Comment: You might get better answers on the computer security site? Over here, we specialize in helping you write code when you know exactly what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We do lot of sanitation of XML document.

XSLT is Open-source platform which is very advanced now. Here is the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/), which helps you cleaning up and vulnerable less message object your XML document

For validation check and conditional based check you can use conditional operations in XSLT. We create templates in XSLT and make sure the XML object is very clean and vulnerable less.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you able to point me to any examples where sanitation is implemented via XSLT?